# Plotting sampling distribution of the sample mean---survey sampling

Tags: probability

My population consists of cca 200 people.
My sample is 20 people.
I have the required data for all the 200 people in the population and I am wondering if it is possible to plot the sampling distribution of the sample mean for the sample size 20. I want to see how close to normal it actually is.

doing it by hand is impossible..since ${200\choose 20}$ is everything but a small number.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simulation is the way to go. You take random samples of size 20 and calculate the sample means. Then you can confirm the sampling distribution.